# How to apply Esc key as double typing in EventHandler?

Tags: front-end, keyboard, eventhandler

I wrote a code to delete the text in `InputField` with the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

```
Manipulate[ ToExpression@in,  
Style[Row[{ EventHandler[ Control@{{in, Null}, InputField[#, Boxes] &,        
Alignment -> {Left, Center},
   ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 10}}, ContinuousAction -> True,
   FrameMargins -> 10, ImageSize -> {400, {50, Automatic}}} ,
 {{"KeyDown", "Escape"} :> {in = Null   } } , 
 PassEventsDown -> False, Method -> "Queued"] }], 20] ]
```

Of course, it works well. But there is one problem.

Shortcuts such as <kbd>Esc</kbd>`intt`<kbd>Esc</kbd> cannot be used.

So I want to set the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to double typing.

Alternatively, you may set it to the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

How do I fix the code?

If you have any ideas for better shortcuts without conflict with other ones, you can suggest!

Comment: 1. Just to make sure, will this be eventually used in Enterprise CDF (just like your previous questions :) )? If so, the trick modifying KeyEventTranslations.tr is probably improper. 2. How about adding a `PasteButton` that'll paste a `\[AliasDelimiter]`?

Comment: Thank you. I wrote the code with shift+esc key, referring to your opinion. Of course, if I don't press shift, I'm free to use esc.